# why does quickCheck create lists of units

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I tried the following from the paper QuickCheck Testing for fun and profit.

```hs
prop_revApp xs ys = reverse (xs ++ ys) == reverse xs ++ reverse ys
```

and it passed even though it should not have.
I ran `verboseCheck` and I see that it is only checking lists of units, i.e.:

```
Passed:
[(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),()]
```

I was wondering why this was.

I am aware I can fix it by defining the type of the property but was wondering if this was necessary or I was missing something.

Comment: Although not the question, isn't this invalid? It looks to me that `reverse (xs ++ ys) == reverse ys ++ reverse xs` (so with `xs` and `ys` swapped).

Comment: As defined, `xs` and `ys` have type `[a]`. I don't know this for a fact, but it makes sense that unspecified types would default to something, and `()` is a good candidate for that something. What would be the basis for generating any other value when you don't tell it what types of value to generate?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the way I understood the question, that's the point. The test should fail, but apparently it passed (as it would if you restricted it to just lists of `()`)

Comment: @RobinZigmond is correct, the paper is specifically showing this as a failing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prop_revApp` function is quite generic:

```
*Main> :t prop_revApp
prop_revApp :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

If you're just loading the code in GHCi, and run it, yes, indeed, the property passes:

```
*Main> quickCheck prop_revApp
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

This is because GHCi comes with a set of preferred defaults. For convenience, it'll try to use the simplest type it can.

It doesn't get much simpler than `()`, and since `()` has an `Eq` instance, it picks that.

If, on the other hand, you actually try to write and compile some properties, the code doesn't compile:

```
import Test.Framework (defaultMain, testGroup)
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2 (testProperty)

import Test.QuickCheck

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain tests

prop_revApp xs ys = reverse (xs ++ ys) == reverse xs ++ reverse ys

tests = [
        testGroup "Example" [
                testProperty "prop_revApp" prop_revApp
           ]
      ]
```

If you try to run these tests with `stack test`, you'll get a compiler error:

```
test\Spec.hs:11:17: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `testProperty'
      prevents the constraint `(Arbitrary a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (Either a b)
          -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
        instance Arbitrary Ordering
          -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
        instance Arbitrary Integer
          -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary'
        ...plus 19 others
        ...plus 61 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: testProperty "prop_revApp" prop_revApp
      In the second argument of `testGroup', namely
        `[testProperty "prop_revApp" prop_revApp]'
      In the expression:
        testGroup "Example" [testProperty "prop_revApp" prop_revApp]
   |
11 |                 testProperty "prop_revApp" prop_revApp
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You'll have to give the property a more specific type; e.g.

```
tests = [
        testGroup "Example" [
                testProperty "prop_revApp" (prop_revApp :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool)
           ]
      ]
```

Now the test compiles, but fails:

```
$ stack test
Q56101904-0.1.0.0: test (suite: Q56101904-test)

Example:
  prop_revApp: [Failed]
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests and 3 shrinks):
[1]
[0]
(used seed -7398729956129639050)

         Properties  Total
 Passed  0           0
 Failed  1           1
 Total   1           1

Q56101904-0.1.0.0: Test suite Q56101904-test failed
Test suite failure for package Q56101904-0.1.0.0
    Q56101904-test:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```